# how to change the value of json file after comparing its element to another json file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I've two json files named one.json and two.json, one.json has multiple projectId's if the value of any ProjectId of one.json matches to ID of two.json the completedCount of two.json should change to completedCount of one.json for the matching ID...
***I don't know how to read or write the JSON file using JavaScript as i'm very new to JavaScript, so any help with that will also be appreciated***
I've tried it using array.

one.json is as follows

```
[ { projectId: '230',
    title: 'Nikhil',
    status: 'Nikhil',
    seenCount: 0,
    inProgressCount: 0,
    completedCount: 30 },
  { projectId: 434,
    title: null,
    status: null,
    seenCount: 0,
    inProgressCount: 0,
    completedCount: 1 } ]
```

two.json is as follows

```
[ { id: '434',
    name: 'project-qa-test',
    customQuestion: 'What did you get done today?',
    maxSyncItems: null,
    orderIndex: 0,
    hidden: false,
    dones: [],
    unReported: 0,
    seenCount: 0,
    inProgressCount: 0,
    completedCount: 0 } ]
```

need to update the value of completedCount in two.json and print it using javaScript...

Comment: So the output of `completedCount` in `two.json` for id 434 should be 1?

Comment: Yesss the out would be 1...

Comment: the solution should be dynamically be able to compare the id and projectId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code should solve your issue of reading, logic and writing into your file.

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

let rawdata_one = fs.readFileSync('one.json');
let rawdata_two = fs.readFileSync('two.json');  
let onedata = JSON.parse(rawdata_one);
let twodata = JSON.parse(rawdata_two);

onedata.forEach(
    function(obj){
        let ob = twodata.findIndex( o => o.id == obj.projectId );
            if(ob != -1){
                twodata[ob].completedCount = obj.completedCount;                    
            }
     }
 )

 let data = JSON.stringify(twodata);  
 fs.writeFileSync('two.json', data);
```

This write will overwrite your two.json with the updated data.

You can also read the json file using require('one.json'). However, it can be done only once in your entire code.

Comment: Yes it did solved the problem thanks a lot i've marked it as the accepted answers can;t upvote it due to my low reputation. thanks again mate...

Answer (score 1):

Slight improvement in above answer :

```
  one.forEach((obj) => { 
      let ob = two.find( o => o.id == obj.projectId );
      if(ob) { ob.completedCount = obj.completedCount };  
      console.log(ob); 
  })
```